# Seedfile not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to run a seedfile and populate a table with data.  My `message` table looks like this:

```
id | copy_for_user_id | senders_id | recipients_id | note | created_at | updated_at | friend_request | category | observed | confirmed | rejected
```

My seedfile looks like this:

```
Message.delete_all

Message.create!({
  copy_for_user_id: 8,
  senders_id: 8,
  recipients_id: 9,
  note: "I love you",
  friend_request: false,
  category: "message",
  observed: false,
  confirmed: false,
  rejected: false
})
```

When I run `rake db:seed` and go back into check my database there is no change.  I'm baffled.  Any ideas?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  It just stalls for a moment, then goes to a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create single object at a time then please use as following, removing `{}` brackets

```
Message.create(copy_for_user_id: 8, senders_id: 8, recipients_id: 9, note: "I love you", 
          friend_request: false, category: "message", observed: false, confirmed: false, rejected: false)
```

Or

```
Message.create!(copy_for_user_id: 8, senders_id: 8, recipients_id: 9, note: "I love you", 
              friend_request: false, category: "message", observed: false, confirmed: false, rejected: false)
```

And If you want to create multiple object at a time then you can pass an array of hash as like

```
Message.create!([{copy_for_user_id: 8, senders_id: 8, recipients_id: 9, note: "I love you",
                friend_request: false, category: "message", observed: false, confirmed: false, rejected: false}])
```

If there is any error it should raise exception, If not work you can try with comment off your model `callback` and `validations` then you can get an idea what is happening.

Comment: Worked.  Thank you very much.  The array part slipped my mind.

Comment: Happy to see it's help you, Welcome :)